# Is Material design are supported in xamarin.native & xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

In our application have a requirement to implement material design in xamarin native android and xamarin forms also. Please let me know it is supported or not.

Comment: Refer- https://blog.xamarin.com/material-design-for-your-xamarin-forms-android-apps/ and https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/designer_overview/part_4_-_material_design_features/

Comment: yes I know it is supported in xamarin.forms but xamarin.native android is supported aha?

Comment: yeah, Ofcourse ! check the above links.. for more you can go with- https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/material_theme/

Answer (score 1):

Material design is fully support in both Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.Forms

For Xamarin.Android, to configure an entire application to use a Material Theme flavor, set the android:theme attribute of the application node in AndroidManifest.xml to one of the following:

```
@android:style/Theme.Material – Dark theme.
@android:style/Theme.Material.Light – Light theme.
@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar – Light theme with dark action bar.
```

For Forms-based Android apps, you must use an AppCompat layer, which allows you to utilize Material design.

Sources:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/material_theme/#Theming_an_Application

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/android/appcompat/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Xamarin form supports Material design you can implement it by adding `Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material`from nuget Manager in your android and iOS project respectively

after that for android add `FormsMaterial.Init(this, savedInstanceState);` in your MainActivity.cs file
and for iOS add `FormsMaterial.Init();` in your AppDeligate.cs file

you are ready to use Material design in your Xamarin project use `Visual="Material"` for the control you need it in material design you can also assign this property to you content page if you need all your controls in material design